# In Django, how to save queried object with datetime attribute?

Tags: python, django, timezone

I'm able to save other attributes of a queried object but not time. Am I missing something with q.edited_datetime = timezone.now()?

```
q = SomeObject.object.get(id=3)
q.title = 'New Title'
q.edited_datetime = timezone.now()
q.save()
```

In models:

```
edited_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

That's basically the code I'm using.

timezone.now() works if I create the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you want to do this automatically in Django, like so:

```
datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
datetime_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

`auto_now_add` will be set only once, the first time.
`auto_now` will be set every time the object is saved.

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield) for more information.